# Reading a bin file in Java

Tags: java, file, filereader

I know that there are some similar questions in the site, but they could not provide me a helpful answer. What is the best/most efficient way to read a .bin file in Java line by line? Which classes and methods should someone use to open it and get the data? Could Bufferedreader do the job or is it only for text files;

Comment: A binary file doesn't have lines.

Comment: The Java Tutorial has a section about [Byte Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html).

Answer (score 1):

Binary file don't have lines, but you must know the format of the file to know what structure exists (headers, structs,etc) and write a parser.

You can use BufferedInputStream, see the following:

- http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245
- [Read structured data from binary file -?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243441/read-structured-data-from-binary-file)

Answer (score -1):

This should do it.

```
public byte[] readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception
{
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
byte[] data = new byte[4096];
int count = inputStream.read(data);
while(count != -1)
{
    dos.write(data, 0, count);
    count = inputStream.read(data);
}

return baos.toByteArray();
}
```