# Transfer binary file(data) in java

Tags: java, c, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to read structured binary files with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277944/best-way-to-read-structured-binary-files-with-java)

I used to be a c programmer. In c, if I want to transfer binary data (not just text file) from std io, I can just do it by calling `getchar()` and `putchar()`over and over again, until reaching `EOF`.
My question is that is that possible to do the same way in Java? Can I just call `readline()` and `writeline()` over and over again? If not, what can I do?
Thank you!

Comment: How about doing some research, and then come back asking questions when you are stuck?  At least, do some googling first.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more clear. Also, please put codes in ` and closing with another`, like: `putchar()`.

Comment: Read the docs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you should absolutely *not* use anything with `readLine()` and `writeLine()` calls. Those are for *text* data. If you're transferring binary data, you should be using `InputStream` and `OutputStream` - nothing with `Reader` or `Writer` in the name. If you convert binary data to text, you're almost guaranteed to lose data.

But then you can just copy blocks of data at a time:

```
public static void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
    throws IOException {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024]; // For example...
   int bytesRead;
   while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
     output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }
}
```